# Make an element take up available horizontal space without causing its parent to widen

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I have a flexbox container with exactly two children, both of which can have variable content. I want the width of the entire container to fit the width of the first child, but I want the second child's contents to wrap and **not** cause the container to grow horizontally. See the runnable snippet below for a visual problem description.

Currently looking for a CSS Grid solution. I have found one partial solution, but relies on JavaScript: Make the second child a relative container, put its contents in an intermediate absolutely-positioned container, and use JS to set a fixed height. At least it's good for showing what I'm looking for.

### Problem:

```css
.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.child {
  background-color: wheat;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first child">
    This content can grow and be as wide as it wants
  </div>
  <div class="second child">
    This content will also be any size it wants, but I * want it to wrap at the asterisk in this sentence, which is where the first child above would naturally end. This will be its own flexbox container holding several buttons that should wrap onto new rows.
  </div>
</div>
```

### JavaScript/absolute solution:

```js
let second = document.getElementsByClassName('second')[0]
let content = document.getElementsByClassName('absolute')[0]

second.style.height = content.offsetHeight + 'px'
```

```css
.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.child {
  background-color: wheat;
  margin: 5px;
}

.second {
  position: relative;
  /* height to be set by JS */
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first child">
    This content can grow and be as wide as it wants
  </div>
  <div class="second child">
    <div class="absolute">
      This content is longer than the above but still wraps in the right place.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm a little unclear what your asking. Do you want both boxes to never take up more than 50% of the width? Eg like a table? or do you want first box to take up AT LEAST 50% of the width and when it grows bigger to shrink the second box? Can you draw a picture or in some other way show what your're trying to get? Your code "solution" looks like two blocks stacked upon each other. Which 
 can be accomplished with `flex-wrap: wrap`.

Comment: sounds familiar too me .. need to find the related question now ..

Comment: Is using Flexbox a requirement?

Comment: "wrap at the asterisk in another different div" is not valid, so you need to clarify what your goal is. Also why would you use `flex-direction:column`, when you clearly need `flex-direction:row` here

Comment: @BryceHowitson, The two children are meant to be vertically stacked. I drew a picture for you in the form of the second code snippet, which produces exactly the result I want.

Comment: @JamesT Flexbox is not a requirement. My goal is to eliminate JS from this solution, which is purely concerned with layout.

Comment: @sweaver2112 That asterisk is just to show you roughly where the wrapping point would be, based on the current content of the first child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set `min-width` and `width` of `.second`:

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}

.child {
  background-color: wheat;
}

.second {
  margin-top: 10px;
  min-width: 100%;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first child">
    This content can grow and be as wide as it wants
  </div>
  <div class="second child">
    This content will also be any size it wants, but I * want it to wrap at the asterisk in this sentence, which is where the first child above would naturally end. This will be its own flexbox container holding several buttons that should wrap onto new rows.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can add padding to the conainer instead of dealing with margin then it will be simple

Comment: @TemaniAfif True. I just wanted a clear distinction between the two children without adding another line of CSS, for brevity's sake.

Comment: A counter-intuitive but functional solution! Thank you, James.